# Postgis isn't an available database backend

Tags: django, postgresql, geodjango

I'm facing this error when setting up geodjango in a working django 1.9 app.

My app is living inside a amazon EC2 instance plus a RDS postgres instance.

The error is:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3
```

What I've done:

- Install GEOS, PROJ.4 and PostGIS as described in [geodjango doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/).
- Install PostGIS in amazon RDS as described in [amazon doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS).
- Modify my project **settings.py** to include:

  - INSTALLED_APPS = (... 'django.contrib.admin', ... 'django.contrib.gis')
  - GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so'
  - DATABASES = { ... 'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' ...}
- Modify my app **models.py** to import models from *django.contrib.gis.db*, instead of *django.db*

Any guess what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you installed `psycopg2`?

Comment: Yes, I've installed python-psycopg2, postgresql-server-dev-9.3, postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 and postgresql-9.3

Comment: Can you please post your entire `settings.py`? I'm guessing there's a typo in there somewhere because if you've followed the documentation it should just work.

Answer (score 9):

**I had the same issue**
i installed the **osgeo**
and then navigated to the missing libraries

```
> # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...) BASE_DIR =
> os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
> TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

and these were the missing libraries for me:

```
 GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal204.dll'
 GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll'
```

Answer (score 5):

Run this command

> sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin

This is described [in this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/)

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I ran `pip install gdal`, which showed error messages about a libffi library missing on my system. After installing the correct library (`libffi6 on AUR`), I ran `pip install gdal` again and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it, as Pacman updated libffi to version 8, but gdal needed version 7 from AUR.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my libgdal library was causing me issues and giving me this error.

I'm working in windows under a conda environment running Django 1.11 and GDAL 2.0. Changing GDAL and django versions didnt seem to fix anything. However, setting the libgdal version to 1.11.2 seemed to clear the error up for me.